# How often should we use the Arrowverse tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag called [arrowverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse) for the shared universe between *Arrow*, *The Flash*, *DC's Legends of Tomorrow*, *Vixen*, and *Constantine*. When questions are about more than one show, it certainly makes sense to tag it with that:

- [Where does Vixen S02E01 fall in Arrowverse timeline?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/62228/12783)
- [Do "Arrow" and "The Flash" share sets?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/49259/12783)
- [Is Gideon on The Flash and Gideon on Legends of Tomorrow same?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46782/12783)

However, there are a number of questions that have been tagged with this, but they only have to do with one show. In most cases, the original poster didn't use the tag, but it was edited in later by another user:

- [Why was the "Green" removed from "Green Arrow"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/5665/12783)
- [What happened to the child Barry Allen in The Flash S3 Premiere?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/61569/12783)
- [Why did Vandal call him by that name and what does it mean or reference?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/47367/12783)

I'm struggling to see the value of the [arrowverse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse) tag if it's always going to be present on any question tagged with [arrow](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrow), for instance. How should we be using it going forward?

Comment: Decision was taken in favor of keeping franchise tag in all the question related to single of multiple property of that franchise long ago, [refer here](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/1878/1190)

Comment: Huh, I wouldn't have thought to look at a question about the Marvel Cinematic Universe for a general guideline about all franchises. Maybe there could be a canonical question?

Comment: That MCU question made the canonical decision and getting applied to every franchise tags from a year now.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's not easy for anybody to find this canonical decision if they don't already know that it's been decided inside of a discussion about the Marvel Cinematic Universe tag. A more general question about our franchise policy would make it easier for others to find.